# TeeChart Geographical GIS in .Net

Tags: .net, teechart

Is it possible to implement multiple layer in teechart map like state,city and highways etc?
I am using shapefile for usa format. For single layer it is working but how can I implement multiple layer.
Also please suggest me , how to use realignment tool to increase the area of any territory. I didn't find any tool like hand free selection tool.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to implement multiple layer in teechart map like
>   state,city and highways etc? I am using shapefile for usa format. For
>   single layer it is working but how can I implement multiple layer.

You can try using multiple map series with a different shape file each.

> Also please suggest me , how to use realignment tool to increase the
>   area of any territory. I didn't find any tool like hand free selection
>   tool.

Steema.TeeChart.Tools.DragPoint doesn't work with Map series. I have added it to Steema's bugzilla ([#1209](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1209)).